# проверить существует ли файл?

Tags: php

как из массива со списком расширениями проверить существует ли файл?

```
$array = array(".jpg", ".png",".gif");
        $name= 'filename';

     if (file_exists('/matherials/'.$name)){
    echo 'файл существует';
     }
```

Как подставить массив с что бы оно сравнивало с одним из значений??

Comment: В цикле прогнать

Comment: @Свободу Сергею Суровцеву, есть какая то конкретика? если поставлю в цикл, то будет Notice: Array to string conversion in .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array(".jpg", ".png", ".gif");
$name = 'filename';

foreach ($array as $item) {
  if (file_exists('/matherials/'.$name.$item)) {
    echo 'файл существует';
  }
}
```